# Graphical glitches around borders and crashes in linux with ASRock X570 and AMD Ryzen 7 3700X

Tags: linux, hardware-failure, desktop

**Problem**
I am experiencing severe problems trying to run linux on my desktop system. Graphical glitches occur even during the installation process (ubuntu/manjaro/kde neon) sometimes so severely that I cannot install the os. After a lot of trouble I managed to install kubuntu 21.04, but the problems persist. The system contains a dual boot with Windows 10, where windows 10 seems to be running stabily.

**Description of the symptoms**
I've constructed a list including images of the symptoms that are occurring, ordered by perceived severity.

1. Occasional random computer shutdown
2. Applications turn completely white after some time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCdLB.jpg

3. Applications show random glitches, usually around the borders.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s83aZ.jpg

4. Firefox crashes really often.

```
AdapterDeviceID: 0x1d01
AdapterDriverVendor: nvidia/unknown
AdapterDriverVersion: 460.67.0.0
AdapterVendorID: 0x10de
Add-ons: reset-search-defaults%40mozilla.com:1.0.6,doh-rollout%40mozilla.org:2.0.0,formautofill%40mozilla.org:1.0,screenshots%40mozilla.org:39.0.0,webcompat%40mozilla.org:20.1.0,google%40search.mozilla.org:1.1,amazondotcom%40search.mozilla.org:1.3,wikipedia%40search.mozilla.org:1.1,bing%40search.mozilla.org:1.3,ddg%40search.mozilla.org:1.1,default-theme%40mozilla.org:1.1,ebay%40search.mozilla.org:1.3,langpack-en-GB%40firefox.mozilla.org:87.0buildid20210318103112,langpack-en-CA%40firefox.mozilla.org:87.0buildid20210318103112
AvailablePageFile: 13162614784
AvailablePhysicalMemory: 29354622976
AvailableSwapMemory: 2147479552
AvailableVirtualMemory: 30026985472
BuildID: 20210318103112
ContentSandboxCapabilities: 119
ContentSandboxCapable: 1
ContentSandboxLevel: 4
CrashTime: 1618606332
DOMIPCEnabled: 1
DesktopEnvironment: kde
ExperimentalFeatures: browser.startup.homepage.abouthome_cache.enabled,network.cookie.sameSite.laxByDefault,network.cookie.sameSite.noneRequiresSecure,network.cookie.sameSite.schemeful,layout.css.constructable-stylesheets.enabled,layout.css.grid-template-masonry-value.enabled,devtools.inspector.color-scheme-simulation.enabled,devtools.inspector.compatibility.enabled,devtools.webconsole.input.context,devtools.debugger.features.windowless-service-workers,fission.autostart,network.http.http3.enabled,image.avif.enabled,media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.allow-multiple,browser.urlbar.keepPanelOpenDuringImeComposition,dom.forms.inputmode,dom.webgpu.enabled,privacy.webrtc.globalMuteToggles
FramePoisonBase: 9223372036600930304
FramePoisonSize: 4096
GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: Failed to create a valid ShmemTextureHost (t=59.3668) |[1][GFX1-]: Failed to create a valid ShmemTextureHost (t=59.3697) |[2][GFX1-]: Failed to create a valid ShmemTextureHost (t=59.4119) |[3][GFX1-]: Failed to create a valid ShmemTextureHost (t=59.4127) |[4][GFX1-]: Failed to create a valid ShmemTextureHost (t=59.4202) |[5][GFX1-]: Failed to create a valid ShmemTextureHost (t=59.4203)
InstallTime: 1617406946
IsWayland: 0
IsWaylandDRM: 0
Notes: Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (development branch)FP(D00-L1000-W00000000-T000) WR? WR- OMTP? OMTP+4
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
RDDProcessStatus: Running
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 3810
StartupCrash: 0
StartupTime: 1618606256
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86-64","buildId":"20210318103112","version":"87.0","vendor":"Mozilla","displayVersion":"87.0","platformVersion":"87.0","xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3","updaterAvailable":false},"partner":{"distributionId":"canonical","distributionVersion":"1.0","partnerId":"ubuntu","distributor":"canonical","distributorChannel":"ubuntu","partnerNames":["ubuntu"]},"system":{"memoryMB":32033,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":16,"cores":8,"vendor":"AuthenticAMD","family":23,"model":113,"stepping":0,"l2cacheKB":512,"l3cacheKB":16384,"speedMHz":4823,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3","hasSSSE3","hasSSE4_1","hasSSE4_2","hasAVX","hasAVX2","hasAES"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"5.11.0-14-generic","locale":"en-US"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null,"type":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null,"type":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null,"type":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"ContentBackend":"Skia","Headless":false,"EmbeddedInFirefoxReality":null,"adapters":[{"description":"GeForce GT 1030/PCIe/SSE2","vendorID":"0x10de","deviceID":"0x1d01","subsysID":null,"RAM":0,"driver":null,"driverVendor":"nvidia/unknown","driverVersion":"460.67.0.0","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[{"screenWidth":2560,"screenHeight":1440}],"features":{"compositor":"basic","hwCompositing":{"status":"blocked:"},"gpuProcess":{"status":"unused"},"wrQualified":{"status":"blocklisted:FEATURE_FAILURE_WEBRENDER_NO_LINUX_NVIDIA"},"webrender":{"status":"disabled:FEATURE_FAILURE_NOT_QUALIFIED"},"wrCompositor":{"status":"disabled:FEATURE_FAILURE_DISABLED"},"wrSoftware":{"status":"denied"},"openglCompositing":{"status":"unavailable:FEATURE_FAILURE_OPENGL_NEED_HWCOMP"},"omtp":{"status":"available"}}},"appleModelId":null},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":true,"e10sMultiProcesses":8,"fissionEnabled":false,"telemetryEnabled":false,"locale":"en-US","intl":{"requestedLocales":["en-US"],"availableLocales":["en-US","en-CA","en-GB"],"appLocales":["en-US","en-CA","en-GB"],"systemLocales":["en-US"],"regionalPrefsLocales":["nl-NL"],"acceptLanguages":["en-US","en"]},"update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":false},"userPrefs":{"browser.search.region":"NL","browser.search.widget.inNavBar":false,"widget.content.allow-gtk-dark-theme":false,"widget.content.gtk-high-contrast.enabled":true},"sandbox":{"effectiveContentProcessLevel":4},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":true,"defaultSearchEngine":"google-canonical","defaultSearchEngineData":{"loadPath":"[other]addEngineWithDetails:google@search.mozilla.org","name":"Google","origin":"default","submissionURL":"https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q="}},"profile":{"creationDate":18719,"firstUseDate":18719},"addons":{"activeAddons":{"reset-search-defaults@mozilla.com":{"version":"1.0.6","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18720,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"Ask the user if they would like to use a specified search engine as the default.","name":"Reset Search Defaults","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18720,"signedState":3},"doh-rollout@mozilla.org":{"version":"2.0.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18730,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"This used to be a Mozilla add-on that supported the roll-out of DoH, but now only exists as a stub t","name":"DoH Roll-Out","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18548},"formautofill@mozilla.org":{"version":"1.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18730,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":null,"name":"Form Autofill","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18548},"screenshots@mozilla.org":{"version":"39.0.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18730,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"Take clips and screenshots from the Web and save them temporarily or permanently.","name":"Firefox Screenshots","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18548},"webcompat@mozilla.org":{"version":"20.1.0","scope":1,"type":"extension","updateDay":18730,"isSystem":true,"isWebExtension":true,"multiprocessCompatible":true,"blocklisted":false,"description":"Urgent post-release fixes for web compatibility.","name":"Web Compatibility Interventions","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18548}},"theme":{"id":"default-theme@mozilla.org","blocklisted":false,"description":"A theme with the operating system color scheme.","name":"Default","userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"version":"1.1","scope":4,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"installDay":18719,"updateDay":18719},"activePlugins":[],"activeGMPlugins":{"gmp-gmpopenh264":{"version":"1.8.1.1","userDisabled":false,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1}}},"experiments":{"bug-1701297-rollout-turn-off-networkjarrecord_failure_reason-release-87-88":{"branch":"active","type":"normandy-prefrollout","enrollmentId":"2c8f40c9-9701-4bba-97e3-94ef3a4a0328"}}}
ThreadIdNameMapping: 1929:"IPC I/O Parent",1930:"Timer",1931:"Netlink Monitor",1932:"Socket Thread",1933:"Permission",1937:"JS Watchdog",1938:"JS Helper",1939:"JS Helper",1940:"JS Helper",1942:"JS Helper",1943:"JS Helper",1944:"JS Helper",1941:"JS Helper",1945:"JS Helper",1948:"Cache2 I/O",1949:"Cookie",1952:"Worker Launcher",1953:"SoftwareVsyncThread",1954:"Compositor",1955:"ImageIO",1956:"IPDL Background",1958:"QuotaManager IO",1966:"DOM Worker",1968:"StreamTrans #12",1971:"TRR Background",1972:"IndexedDB #1",1974:"StyleThread#0",1977:"StyleThread#3",1975:"StyleThread#1",1978:"StyleThread#4",1979:"StyleThread#5",1976:"StyleThread#2",1980:"ImageBridgeChld",1981:"Breakpad Server",1983:"IPC Launch",1986:"GMPThread",1989:"FS Broker 1984",1990:"ProcessHangMon",2008:"TaskController Thread #0",2009:"TaskController Thread #1",2010:"TaskController Thread #2",2011:"TaskController Thread #3",2012:"TaskController Thread #4",2013:"TaskController Thread #5",2014:"TaskController Thread #6",2015:"TaskController Thread #7",2020:"BackgroundThreadPool #1",2023:"DNS Resolver #1",2025:"Cache I/O",2026:"HTML5 Parser",2027:"DNS Resolver #2",2028:"DNS Resolver #3",2029:"DNS Resolver #4",2031:"StreamTrans #16",2032:"DOM Worker",2037:"FS Broker 2033",2048:"mozStorage #1",2053:"localStorage DB",2054:"localStorage DB",2060:"mozStorage #2",2061:"mozStorage #3",2084:"FS Broker 2066",2092:"DOM Worker",2093:"URL Classifier",2096:"SSL Cert #1",2106:"BgIOThreadPool #1",2142:"FS Broker 2128",2161:"mozStorage #4",2169:"StreamTrans #18",2188:"mozStorage #5",2201:"SSL Cert #2",2202:"SSL Cert #3",2211:"mozStorage #6",2213:"mozStorage #7",2234:"FS Broker 2219",2273:"FS Broker 2269",2293:"DNS Resolver #5",2294:"DNS Resolver #6",2295:"DNS Resolver #7",2296:"DNS Resolver #8",2384:"FS Broker 2370",2422:"FS Broker 2419",2487:"FS Broker 2480",2551:"FS Broker 2537",2608:"SSL Cert #4",
Throttleable: 1
TotalPageFile: 35736969216
TotalPhysicalMemory: 33589489664
URL: https://812c42adaf838456864f814b69e94d0b.safeframe.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-38/html/container.html
UptimeTS: 75.72383799
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 87.0
useragent_locale: en-US
```

**My hardware**
The hardware configuration that I have is the following:

1. ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming 4
2. AMD Ryzen 7 3700X
3. 2x16GB Corsair Vengeance 3200MHz
4. 2x Samsung 970 EVO PLUS, one for windows one for linux.
5. Asus NVIDIA GT 1030

**My diagnostics**
I've tried a great number of things prior to posting this problem here. I've constructed a list of my hypotheses and tests.

6. My initial hypothesis was a wrong gpu driver. I've installed a multitude of drivers, nouveau, nvidia various versions, across multiple linux oses (ubuntu, manjaro, arch, kde neon) but every setup has similar problems.
7. Then I figured it could be a faulty GPU. So I swapped to a GT710, GTX 2070 SUPER, and a GTX 3070 all with the exact same issues.
8. Then I figured it could be the SSD. So I installed linux on the other SSD but still the same issues.
9. Finally I thought it could be the RAM which is configured at running at 3200MHz. I've set it to various slower modes and I've run a full memtest both to no avail.
10. Furthermore I've monitored the CPU temperatures after the random shutdowns but it is in the normal range 60 degrees celcius.
11. I've also tried other monitors and other HDMI/DP cables.

**my current hypothesis**
At this point the only hypothesis I can come up with is a faulty motherboard or CPU. I would really appreciate some feedback before I return my hardware because it seems to be running stably in Windows and I am afraid I will lose my hardware for months only to get it back with no found issues.

**EDIT 1**
Although Windows runs mostly stable, some applications do have some weird behavior. In particular:

1. Netflix (firefox) occasionally stops playing and gives an error code.
2. Firefox tabs occasionally become unselectable/unresponsive or crash requiring a manual reload.
3. Discord seems to crash quite often, sometimes like once every minute after which it auto restarts.

Furthermore I've flashed my motherboard BIOS to the newest version but also that didn't help.

**EDIT 2**
As requested by @HolyBlackCat I ran the following command.

```
journalctl | grep -i 'hardware error'
```

```
apr 16 21:27:43 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
apr 16 21:27:43 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 25: 80004000003e0000
apr 16 21:27:43 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 IPID 100ff03830400  
apr 16 21:27:43 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:870f10 TIME 1618601261 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 8701013
apr 16 22:15:33 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
apr 16 22:15:33 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 11: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000000108
apr 16 22:15:33 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 7f203b8562b2 MISC d012000100000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 500b000000000  
apr 16 22:15:33 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:870f10 TIME 1618604131 SOCKET 0 APIC 7 microcode 8701013
apr 16 22:18:21 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
apr 16 22:18:21 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 3: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000000108
apr 16 22:18:21 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 7f48a87ba058 MISC d012000100000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 500b000000000  
apr 16 22:18:21 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:870f10 TIME 1618604298 SOCKET 0 APIC 6 microcode 8701013
apr 17 15:31:57 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
apr 17 15:31:57 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 3: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000000108
apr 17 15:31:57 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 7ff4a2d1f0ce MISC d012000100000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 500b000000000  
apr 17 15:31:57 shadash-desktop-linux kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:870f10 TIME 1618666315 SOCKET 0 APIC 6 microcode 8701021
```

Comment: Does `journalctl | grep -i 'hardware error'` print anything?

Comment: Yes it prints errors @HolyBlackCat! See my update.

Comment: But now I'm not sure what to do with those. When I had random reboots on Ryzen 5 3600 (also reported by this command in a similar way), disabling PBO in bios helped.

Comment: Today I've also experienced glitches in Windows 10, specifically small black squares in a diagonal pattern all over the screen. I have called with my supplier and they will test my mb and cpu combi.

Comment: Well the cpu and mb were returned by the supplier, saying they could not replicate the issue...